# How to get indicators back in top panel on GNOME 3?

Tags: gnome, icons, configuration, gnome-shell, system-tray

I have recently installed Ubuntu Gnome with Gnome 3 running on it. I have installed various programs on it which in Unity would have a little icon which would go on the right on the Unity panel, such as Skype, Steam, and Shutter. However in Gnome when launching these applications I see no such icons appearing anywhere.

- So do they appear somewhere?
- Can I make them appear somewhere (such as where they would appear in
  Unity) if not?

Comment: The indicators are placed at the bottom of the workspace. Move the mouse down and the notification area will be shown. At the right hand side are the indicators.

Comment: @A.B.: Nope, I do not see that.

Comment: Hmm, interesting :\

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [AppIndicator support](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/615/appindicator-support/) extension for gnome.

Open a browser and go to the [Gnome Extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/615/appindicator-support/) page.

[image]

Click the “Off” button to “On” to install the extension in Gnome Shell.

Once activated, you should see the appindicator icons in your system tray.

[image]

Configuring the Appindicator support
If you have not installed Gnome Tweak Tool, install it with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Open up Gnome Tweak Tool and go to the “Gnome Shell Extension”. Click the Tool icon beside the extension.

[image]

In the Options section, you can configure the default position of the appindicator, whether they will appear in the top panel, message tray or hide completely. You can also change the position for individual appindicator.

[image]

<sub>All rights goes to the [owner](https://www.maketecheasier.com/enable-appindicator-in-gnome-shell/).</sub>

There is also a bug report here requesting to have it installed by default: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1477216

Comment: Why does Gnome not have AppIndicator enabled support by default?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda This related to the extension developer and Gnome itself. I can't answer that