# How do I make taskbar icons appear in GNOME?

Tags: gnome, icons

In Unity, I see running programs such as Dropbox or Pidgin in the taskbar (the icons also change when dropbox is updating or I have received a new message in Pidgin).

However, when I switched to GNOME these icons disappeared, even though the program is still running. A similar question was asked here:

[Running programs are not displayed in the panel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63633/running-programs-are-not-displayed-in-the-panel)

But this question is for Ubuntu 10.x, and I don't see the "bottom panel" this question is referring to.

I have the same problem on my work and home PCs, so I suspect this is not an artefact of my particular installation.

How can I get these icons back?

Comment: Which GNOME version?

Comment: @A.B. version `3.9.90`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GNOME 3, you should be able to see programs' app indicators by "pushing" the mouse cursor against the bottom edge of the screen. The panel will then appear from the bottom edge.

Comment: Well, that only seems to work intermittently, and for only some of the programs, and I can't see it all the time. Is there a better option?

Comment: @quant Maybe this is what you're looking for? http://askubuntu.com/q/651367/18612